# How do I calculate the next/previous ISO weekday number?

Tags: date-arithmetic, iso8601, dayofweek, weekday, nodatime

The [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculation) numbers weekdays 1 for Monday through to 7 for Sunday.
Given a weekday number from 1 to 7, how do you calculate the number of the next/previous weekday?

E.g. given 1, the next weekday number would be 2, and the previous would be 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weekday numbers can be calculated with simple addition and modulo. The formulas are as follows:

**Next weekday number**

> (weekday number % 7) + 1

**Previous weekday number**

> ((weekday number + 5) % 7) + 1

---

Using C# and NodaTime's IsoDayOfWeek, you can create two simple extensions methods like:

```cs
public static IsoDayOfWeek NextDay( this IsoDayOfWeek dayOfWeek ) => (IsoDayOfWeek)( (int)dayOfWeek % 7 + 1 );
public static IsoDayOfWeek PreviousDay( this IsoDayOfWeek dayOfWeek ) => (IsoDayOfWeek)( (int)( dayOfWeek + 5 ) % 7 + 1 );
```